# WPF c# window navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

i got 2 window , i want to navigate from one another but i when i debug it , it shows that nav is null , why is that so? Does it suppose to be null? because i used the same way to navigate in the past and it work and i try it now , it doesn't work. But if i put nav == null , it says

> nav.Navigate(new Uri("HomeMenu.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

is null

here is what i have :

```
            NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
        if (nav != null)
        {
            nav.Navigate(new Uri("HomeMenu.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
```

is this how i can navigate from a Window to user control page?

Comment: Try to put Frame in your MainWindow and navigate through Frame.

Answer (score 1):

GetNavigationService returns null when the dependencyObject:

- Is a NavigationWindow.
- Is a Frame that:

  1) Is hosted by another navigator.

  2) Has its JournalOwnership property set to UsesParentJournal.
- Is not part of content that is hosted by a navigator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.getnavigationservice.aspx